# nested div CSS selector

Tags: css

I have DOM like this

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

and corresponding CSS is like

```
.outer {
   width: 700px;
}
```

, where `inner` could by `typeA`, `typeB`.....

Later I found that I want to enlarge `outer` when particular `typeX` show up, but

```
.outer .typeX {
   width: 90%;
}
```

will apply style `width: 90%` to `.typeX` div not `.outer` div. How do I solve this? Is it possible in pure CSS? (Assume `.outer` is fixed since it is generated by other library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are looking for would be a parent selector, [**which does not yet exist in CSS.**](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)

Maybe someday (e.g., in [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/)).